# regex to match a word containing at-least one 'x' but not containing any 'y'

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to match a word at the beginning of the string/line containing at-least one `/`. A word may contain any alphanumeric or special characters. i.e. a word with non-space characters containing at-least one `/`.

For example,

```
a/b/c 1.2 1.0    # match
a/b-d/c 1.2 1.0    # match
a_b_c 1.2 1.0    # NO match
a/b_c 1.2 1.0    # match
```

`^\S+` or `^[^ ]+` can fetch first word but can't figure out how to guarantee at-least one `/` in it.

In general, I am looking for a regex to match a string containing at-least one '**x**' but not containing any '**y**'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following regex should work for you:

```
 ^(?=[^\/\s]*\/)\S+
```

lookahead will make sure presence of at least one `/` in the first word.

**Suggested by OP: This regex should also work:**

```
^[^ ]*\/[^ ]*
```

**TESTING:**

```
 var re = /^(?=[^\/\s]*\/)\S+/;

 re.test('/abc'); // true
 re.test('abc/'); // true
 re.test('abc /def'); // false
 re.test('a-b-c /def'); // false
 re.test('/ /def'); // true
 re.test(' /def'); // false
 re.test('/def'); // false
```

Comment: @jkshah: That wasn't my intention but just wanted to provide a better and more accurate answer.

Comment: but wasn't that simple and elegant? I mean `^[^y]*x[^y]*`. No look-ahead so can work in `grep`, `sed` anywhere?

Comment: @jkshah: That won't work. `/^[^\/]*\s[^\/]*/.test('/abc');` returns false

Comment: It seems you swapped x and y. Try `^[^ ]*\/[^ ]*`

Comment: Thanks for confirming. that's not my suggestion, it's from previous ans! I would like to accept that for original idea, while keeping your alternate solution in mind for future.